# Using an XML file's tags and attributes to loop in a PHP document is not working

Tags: javascript, xml, for-loop

I'm having trouble figuring out why this isn't looping. Just for testing purposes, I have included just two equipment tags that have all this information within this tag. Equipment-syndication is the main tag here. Here is my code:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else // for IE 5/6
{
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET","http://stage.pithlabs.com/cat/wp-content/themes/cat-child/test.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
document.write("XML document loaded into an XML DOM Object.");
document.write("<table><tr><th>Equipment ID</th><th>Price</th><th>Dealer Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Features</th><th>Images</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("equipment-syndication");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("equipment")[0].getAttribute('id'));
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("contact")[0].getAttribute('first-name'));
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("contact")[0].getAttribute('last-name'));

    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("category-class")[0].getAttribute('name'));

    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("category-class")[0].getAttribute('name'));

    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write('<img src="'+x[i].getElementsByTagName("photo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'"><br>'); 
    document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

Now I know everything is correct because I can see the xml file being generated on the front end. I can see the ID, the name, an image... All that stuff. Am I getting the loop wrong? It's supposed to add another row if there is more than one "Equipment" element tag, right?

Here is the basic structure of the xml file I'm working with:

```
<equipment-syndication>
   <equipment id="">
      <price></price>
      <product></product>
      <features>
         <feature></feature>
         <feature></feature>
      </features>
      <photos></photos>
   </equipment>
   <equipment id="">
      <price></price>
      <product></product>
      <features></features>
      <photos></photos>
    </equipment>
</equipment-syndication>
```

Comment: It helps if you add a tag for the language you're using , so that people who are familiar with that tag see your question. XML doesn't have a for loop, and that's certainly not XML in your first code block. Please [edit] to do so. Thanks.

Comment: if you have to run the loop for "equipment" elements, shouldn't you use `var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("equipment");` to get the `equipment` nodes instead of `equipment-syndication` ?

Comment: @KenWhite I just gave the snippet of the code because the rest of the code is <html><head><body> tags.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("equipment-syndication");
```

returns only one element - the XML root. You need to change your code to

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("equipment")
```

to get all `equipment` elements.

Of course this also indicates changes inside for-loop, but probably only in this line: `x[i].getAttribute('id')`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It was giving me a headache.

Comment: Would I use the same code for tag name within a tagname to loop that?

Comment: @StephenB could you explain your question?